# Beautiful Soup parse Table return only the last row

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to parse an HTML Table with BeautifulSoup. My problem is that I get only the values for the last row. 
feature_list.append(features) add a dict for every row. At the end every dict in feature_list has the same values, but as you can see print(features['Code']) delivers the "Code" for every line.

Can anyone help me out?

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from bs4.element import Tag
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import requests

    def read_item_list_view(url):
        html_doc = requests.get(url, timeout=5).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

        #parse generic features and item information
        generic_features = {}

        generic_features['Titel'] = soup.select_one('.field-name-title').string
        generic_features['Image'] = soup.select_one('.field-name-field-immagine-prodotto').a.img['src']

        generic_features_list = soup.select_one('.field-group-div')

        for feature in generic_features_list.children:
            generic_features[feature.div.string[:-2]] = feature.a.string

        if soup.select_one('.field-name-field-note-prodotto').contents:
            notes = []
            for string in soup.select_one('.field-name-field-note-prodotto').stripped_strings:
                notes.append(string)
            generic_features['Notes'] = notes

        #find feature table
        table = soup.select_one('.field-name-product-dimensions-press-fitting').find('table')

        #read html table with simple header
        def read_table_with_simple_header(table, generic_features):
            header = []
            feature_list = []
            features = generic_features
            table_header = table.thead
            for tr in table_header.contents:
                if isinstance(tr, Tag):
                    for col in tr.children:
                        if isinstance(col, Tag):
                            header.append(col.text.strip())
            table_content = table.tbody
            for tr in table_content.contents:
                if isinstance(tr, Tag):
                    cur_col = 0
                    for col in tr.children:
                        if isinstance(col, Tag):
                            features[header[cur_col]] = col.text.strip()
                            cur_col += 1
                    print(features['Code'])
                    feature_list.append(features)
            return feature_list

        return read_table_with_simple_header(table, generic_features)

    print(read_item_list_view('https://www.vitillo.eu/de/press-fittings/metric-female-24deg-cone-90deg-elbow-l-type.html'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because dictionaries are a mutable type, meaning that when you change the 'features' dictionary on each loop it is updating the same 'features' object each time, which affects the previously appended 'features' (i.e. they are all the same object. You are just appending a new reference to it each time)

What you want to do is append a new dictionary object each time.

Change

```
feature_list.append(features)
```

to

```
feature_list.append(dict(features))
```

and I think this will solve your problem.